# I tried the following, and checked this.props in Table, but only seeing __proto__: Object in `this.props.routeParams`

Tags: javascript

I tried the following, and checked this.props in Table, but only seeing **proto**: Object in `this.props.routeParams`.I tried the following, and checked this.props in Table, but only seeing **proto**: Object in `this.props.routeParams`.I tried the following, and checked this.props in Table, but only seeing **proto**: Object in `this.props.routeParams`.

Comment: Please don't deface your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Home :

```
<Link to="/table" state={{query: userInfo}}>
  <div>
     Pass userInfo Object to Table Route
  </div>
</Link>
```

## Table :

```
componentDidMount () { 
   console.log(
     this.props.location.state 
  ) //{query: userInfo}
}
```

Comment: Good catch. Thank you!